# js causing firefox to crash

Tags: javascript, firefox, crash

I apologize for the vague question, but I don't know how to better describe what is happening.

I'm developing a web app that so far is strictly coded in js (no server side code yet). I'm using an HTML 5 canvas to draw a sort of layout diagram that has click events and color coding and selecting of objects etc etc.

I'm developing this strictly for use with Firefox (I'm using moz specific css stuff and Storage which the version of IE I have to use doesn't support.)

Today while working on my project I started experiencing odd behavior. When loading the web page some of the content would appear (buttons, divs etc) and then Firefox would pop up a dialog stating "Firefox has stopped working" and asks if I want to "Check online for a solution and close the program" or just "Close the program". The following was in the "further details" pane:

```
> Problem signature:   Problem Event Name:  APPCRASH   Application
> Name: firefox.exe   Application Version:  17.0.4.4814   Application
> Timestamp:    5138e84f   Fault Module Name:   mozjs.dll   Fault Module
> Version:  0.0.0.0   Fault Module Timestamp:   5138d295   Exception
> Code: c0000005   Exception Offset:    0002171f   OS
> Version:  6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4   Locale ID:   1033   Additional
> Information 1:    0a9e   Additional Information
> 2:    0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789   Additional Information 3:    0a9e  
> Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
> 
> Read our privacy statement online:  
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

I put some alert statements in my code and traced down the problem to a certain block of code. However if I step through that block (putting an alert statement in each iteration of a for loop) the code executes as expected, and Firefox doesn't crash. Firebug doesn't see anything wrong with the code either. If I take the alert away then suddenly Firefox chokes again.

If I break that portion of code out and run it by clicking a button, then the code executes properly as well, however it's not practical for my users to have to click the button to make it work.

I need help figuring out what I should try to zero in on the problem.

A few things that may (I have no idea) be relevant:

I'm loading data from about 12 different xml documents, one as big as 600KB, the rest about 20KB.

I'm importing 15 different js libraries as well-- I can potentially reduce this number, but the functionality is broken up logically among these files, so it'll make it a little harder to develop if I have to concatenate them all together.

I'm not using jQuery or MooTools or any other libraries like that.

Any ideas on how to work out what's going on?

**EDIT:**

Here is the code for the function that it dies on. The reason I didn't post the actual code was because, as I said, the code itself executes properly when not run with the rest of the code of the page. Still, if it helps, here it is.

```
function GetSeatPaths(Seats){
    // fills the SeatPath, ArmrestPath and SimpleSeatPath for the seat instance (used for cango drawing)

    for (var i =0; i<Seats.length; i++){
        var ThisSeat = Seats[i];

        var SeatPath = ThisSeat.SeatPath;

        //alert("SeatCollection.prototype.GetSeatPaths: " + i);

        if (typeof(SeatPath) === "undefined" || SeatPath == null){

            var Column = ThisSeat.Column;
            var Dims = ThisSeat.Dims;

            if (Column != "Left"){
                BL = -1;
            } else {
                BL = 1;
            }

            var SeatRad = 2;

            try{
                var seat_pax = parseInt(Dims.Seat_PAX); 
            } catch(err){
                var seat_pax = 3;
            }

            if (isNaN(seat_pax)){
                var seat_pax = 3;
            }

            //Make an armrest and cushion set var SeatRad = 2; //this is the radius of the seat cushions
            //alert("getSeatPaths");



            var CTS = 2.25;
            var TAR = 16;
            var CRP = 16.2;
            var BA = 18;
            var FOA = -2;
            var SBT2 = 23.2;
            var ACO = 45;

            if (Dims.hasOwnProperty('CTS')){
                CTS = parseFloat(Dims.CTS.Value);
            } 

            if (Dims.hasOwnProperty('TAR')){
                TAR = parseFloat(Dims.TAR.Value);
            } 

            if (Dims.hasOwnProperty('CRP')){
                CRP = parseFloat(Dims.CRP.Value);
            } 

            if (Dims.hasOwnProperty('BA')){
                BA = parseFloat(Dims.BA.Value);
            } 

            if (Dims.hasOwnProperty('FOA')){
                FOA = parseFloat(Dims.FOA.Value);
            } 

            if (Dims.hasOwnProperty('SBT2')){
                SBT2 = parseFloat(Dims.SBT2.Value);
            } 

            if (Dims.hasOwnProperty('ACO')){
                ACO = parseFloat(Dims.ACO.Value);
            } 

            SeatGeometryArr = [];
            ArmrestGeometryArr = [];

            var SeatOffset = 0
            for (var j=0; j<seat_pax; j++){
                var CW = 17;
                var q = 4;

                if (Dims.hasOwnProperty('CW' + (j+1))){
                    CW = parseFloat(Dims['CW' + (j+1)].Value);
                }

                if (Dims.hasOwnProperty('q' + (j+1))){
                    CW = parseFloat(Dims['q' + (j+1)].Value);
                }

                SeatGeometryArr.push(['M',-CTS+SeatRad,-TAR+q/2 + SeatOffset]);
                SeatGeometryArr.push(['A',SeatRad,SeatRad,0,0,1,-CTS,-TAR+q/2+SeatRad + SeatOffset]);
                SeatGeometryArr.push(['L',-CTS,-TAR+q/2+CW-q/2-SeatRad + q/2 + SeatOffset]);
                SeatGeometryArr.push(['A',SeatRad,SeatRad,0,0,1,-CTS+SeatRad,-TAR+CW+q/2 + SeatOffset]);
                SeatGeometryArr.push(['L',CRP-SeatRad, -TAR+q/2+CW + SeatOffset]);
                SeatGeometryArr.push(['A',SeatRad,SeatRad,0,0,1,CRP, -TAR+q/2+CW-SeatRad + SeatOffset]);
                SeatGeometryArr.push(['L',CRP, -TAR+q/2+SeatRad + SeatOffset]);
                SeatGeometryArr.push(['A',SeatRad,SeatRad,0,0,1,CRP-SeatRad, -TAR+q/2 + SeatOffset]);
                SeatGeometryArr.push(['L',-CTS+SeatRad,-TAR+q/2 + SeatOffset]);
                SeatGeometryArr.push(['Z']);

                SeatGeometryArr.push(['M',CRP+SeatRad,-TAR+q/2 + SeatOffset]); 
                SeatGeometryArr.push(['A',SeatRad,SeatRad,0,0,1,CRP,-TAR+q/2+SeatRad + SeatOffset]);
                SeatGeometryArr.push(['L',CRP,-TAR+q/2+CW-SeatRad + SeatOffset]);
                SeatGeometryArr.push(['A',SeatRad,SeatRad,0,0,1, CRP+SeatRad, -TAR+q/2+CW + SeatOffset]);
                SeatGeometryArr.push(['L',SBT2 - SeatRad ,-TAR+q/2+CW + SeatOffset]);
                SeatGeometryArr.push(['A',SeatRad,SeatRad,0,0,1, SBT2, -TAR + q/2 + CW - SeatRad + SeatOffset]);
                SeatGeometryArr.push(['L',SBT2,-TAR + q/2 + SeatRad+ SeatOffset]);
                SeatGeometryArr.push(['A',SeatRad,SeatRad,0,0,1, SBT2 - SeatRad,-TAR+q/2 + SeatOffset]);
                SeatGeometryArr.push(['L',CRP+SeatRad,-TAR+q/2 + SeatOffset]);
                SeatGeometryArr.push(['Z']);
                SeatOffset += CW;
            }
            //alert("Out of Cushions");
            var SeatPath = FlipGeoArr(SeatGeometryArr,-BL); // Note: BL is flipped here because the geometry for the seat is defined for a RH seat

            // Create Armrest Geometry
            ArmrestGeometryArr = [];
            SeatOffset = 0
            for (var j=0; j<seat_pax+1; j++){
                var CW = 17;
                var q = 4;

                if (Dims.hasOwnProperty('CW' + (j+1))){
                    CW = parseFloat(Dims['CW' + (j+1)].Value);
                }

                if (Dims.hasOwnProperty('q' + (j+1))){
                    CW = parseFloat(Dims['q' + (j+1)].Value);
                }

                ArmrestGeometryArr.push(['M',-FOA,-TAR + SeatOffset]);
                ArmrestGeometryArr.push(['L',-FOA,-TAR+q + SeatOffset]);
                ArmrestGeometryArr.push(['L',BA,-TAR+q + SeatOffset]);
                ArmrestGeometryArr.push(['L',BA,-TAR + SeatOffset]);
                ArmrestGeometryArr.push(['L',-FOA,-TAR + SeatOffset]);
                ArmrestGeometryArr.push(['Z']);
                SeatOffset += CW;
            }
            //alert("Out of Armrests");
            var ArmrestPath = FlipGeoArr(ArmrestGeometryArr,-BL); // Note: BL is flipped here because the geometry for the seat is defined for a RH seat

            //alert("Into Simple");
            // create geometry for the simplified seat
            SimpleSeatGeometryArr = [];
            SimpleSeatGeometryArr.push(['M',-CTS,-TAR]);
            SimpleSeatGeometryArr.push(['L',-CTS,ACO]);
            SimpleSeatGeometryArr.push(['L',SBT2,ACO]);
            SimpleSeatGeometryArr.push(['L',SBT2,-TAR]);
            SimpleSeatGeometryArr.push(['Z']);
            //alert("Out of Simple");
            var SimpleSeatPath = FlipGeoArr(SimpleSeatGeometryArr,-BL); // Note: BL is flipped here because the geometry for the seat is defined for a RH seat

            // stick these values in for all seat instances with this part number
            for (var j=0; j<Seats.length; j++){
                if (Seats[j].PartNumber == Seats[i].PartNumber){
                    Seats[j].SeatPath = SeatPath;
                    Seats[j].ArmrestPath = ArmrestPath;
                    Seats[j].SimpleSeatPath = SimpleSeatPath;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I thought it might be a race condition, too, so I tired using `window.setTimeout(functionThatBreaks,1)` to make sure it executed when it's dependencies were loaded, but to no avail. The same error pops up and FF dies. Is there anything else I can do, short of a user interaction to try and determine if it's a race condition?

**EDIT 4-17-2013, 2:00 PM PST**
I revised the code above to show the changes made at the suggestion of lib3d and TheBrain. I also tried making it a regular function rather than an object prototype, still no change in the behavior.

I also just discovered something peculiar. If I have FireBug active for the website, it runs fine. If I disable FireBug then FireFox crashes. I'm absolutely confused now.

**EDIT 4-17-2013 4:05 PST**
It turns out I was wrong about FireBug causing issues. I can close the browser, reopen it by opening the html page from a folder on my computer and it'll fail. I can do nothing other than click "Close Window" in the Firefox failure dialog, then open the same html page, and suddenly it works.

What might cause this sort of behavior?

Comment: You said you narrowed the problem down to a block of code...post that.

Comment: Race condition...? The JS code may be getting run too early.

Comment: Have you tried [safe mode](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode) to exclude addon issues? If it's reproducible could you report this at [bugzilla.mozilla.org](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/) with a stand-alone test-case or link?

Comment: @jahroy: sorry about not posting code-- like I said, the code itself seems fine when run independently. I've added it to the question above just in case though.

Comment: @MattCoughlin: Any ideas on how to determine if it is a race condition when the first symptom is the browser dying?

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche: I tried safe mode and it doesn't seem to have any effect. If it's a reproducible bug I'll report it as you suggest, but I need to track down what precisely is causing the problem first, I think.

Comment: every time i managed to kill firefox was either because of flash player or because some infinite loop that filled the memory until FF had a mental brake down. perhaps if you break the execution with an alert, the GC has time to do something about it, or it only happens after 2 million iterations and since you didn't press OK that many times you assume is ok.

Comment: Try catch statements are somehow something that can have strange behaviours temporarily in some FF and other browsers patches. Moreover, don't use try catch statements if you don't need to. In your case you really don't.

Comment: @TheBrain thanks for the advice. There weren't _that_ many iterations. It'll break with as few as 60 iterations, which shouldn't be consuming so much memory. I stepped through one iteration at a time using alert boxes and it clicked through ok. You'd expect that reducing the number of iterations below some critical memory value would resolve the issue, right?

Comment: @lib3d: I replaced all the try/catch statements with `if (Dims.hasOwnProperty(DimName)) {...}` which is cleaner anyway, but it didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Then I don't see sensible lines. What I would have done differently: no multiple push -> concat, no parseFloat and parseInt-> cast with "+" operator and check the result is < Infinity. Moreover do you use DOM cloneNode function? The recursive argument has to be set : its default value is not the same as with other browsers

Comment: can you add a console.log on each `catch` and count how many errors you get ? because try catches are very expensive and perhaps they mess the browser up. Check this out http://jsperf.com/try-catch-002 , http://jsperf.com/try-catch-versus-massive-if On the last one try catch don't even show up in the graph. Also, do some memory profiling with Chrome dev tools (on the Timeline tab under Memory).

Comment: @TheBrain: I replaced all the try/catch blocks with if statements as you suggested (Great reference regarding the speed of if vs try catch vs ifIsNull, too. Thanks!) I'm able to ensure that no errors are caught by fiddling with the input data, and even with no errors, it still kills FireFox.

Comment: I agree with Georg Fritzsche, if it's a reproducible crash, then it is a bug. Also, writing a reduced test case might guide you to what causes the crash. few guidelines: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Bug_writing_guidelines